# How to put matrix1 as an element of matrix2?

Tags: python, matrix

I have a matrix M 4x4:

```
[[0. 1. 1. 2.]
 [1. 0. 2. 1.]
 [1. 2. 0. 1.]
 [2. 1. 1. 0.]]
```

And a matrix M1, M2 and M0 2x2, respectfully:

```
[[1. 0.]    [[2. 0.]    [[0. 0.]
 [0. 1.]]    [0. 2.]]    [0. 0.]]
```

Now, if M(i,j)==0 I want to put there M0, if M(i,j)==1 I want to put M1 and if M(i,j)==2, M2.
As a result I want to have matrix 8x8:

```
[[0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 2. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 2.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0. 2. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 2. 0. 1.]
 [1. 0. 2. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 2. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [2. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 2. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0.]]
```

Is there some smart way to do this,literally putting one matrix (M0,1,2) as an element of M? Or I have to create M=8x8 and put the numbers by hands?

Comment: I assume those are numpy arrays

Comment: So your expected output cannot occurr because there is no matrix [1, 0], [0, 1]

Comment: You're right, it is just typo, I am going to correct this, thanks.

Comment: Strictly speaking, putting a matrix "as an element" will result in a matrix of matrices.

Comment: I had a problem with putting it into words, so I included the exact matrix I expect. I hope that despite this horrible inaccuracy, my question is fully understood.

Answer (score 2):

You create a (3,2,2) array and give the indices to this array. Then change the axis and reshape to get your desired array

```
# np.array([M0,M1,M2]) is (3,2,2) array.
# get the array of matrices, np.array([M0,M1,M2])[M]
np.array([M0,M1,M2])[M.astype(int)].transpose(0,2,1,3).reshape(M.shape[0]*M0.shape[0],-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[0., 1., 1., 2.],
                [1., 0., 2., 1.],
                [1., 2., 0., 1.],
                [2., 1., 1., 0.]], dtype=np.int32)

M1 = np.array([[0., 1.],
               [1., 0.]])

M2 = np.array([[0., 2.],
               [2., 0.]])

M0 = np.array([[0., 0.],
               [0., 0.]])

blocks = np.array([M0, M1, M2])
res = np.block([blocks[row].reshape((-1, 2)) for row in arr])

print(res)
```